# Multi-hosting ssl/https site in apache /2.4.7 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-server, https, web-hosting

I have been trying to host 2 site site A and site B in apache web server the configuration are given bellow:

**Site A**

```
<VirtualHost sitea.com.au:443>
ServerName "sitea.com"
ServerAlias sitea.com
DocumentRoot "/home/sitea.com"
.......
</VirtualHost>
```

**Site B**

```
<VirtualHost siteb.com.au:443>
ServerName "siteb.com"
ServerAlias siteb.com
DocumentRoot "/home/siteb.com"
.......
</VirtualHost>
```

The issue I am facing is: Site A https requests are working properly, but for site B all the request are redirected to site A. When I remove the site A configuration file, site B is working properly. Individually sites are working fine, but together they are causing issue.

Comment: Why do you have names in the `<VirtualHost>`?

Comment: I have tried removing the name too like <VirtualHost *:443> but still not working

Comment: Michael Hampton has right, with `*:443` should it work, your current version doesn't help anything. What are doing the `""`-s after your `ServerName`? They doesn't look really okay. Try to use simply `siteb.com`, instead of `"siteb.com"`.

Comment: Thanks Michael and peterh, tried that removing " " but it didn't helped

Comment: What gives an `apachectl -S`? Can you see both of your vhosts in its output?

Comment: *:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server sitea.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sitea.com.conf:28)
         port 443 namevhost sitea.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sitea.com.conf:28)
                 alias sitea.com
         port 443 namevhost siteb.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteb.com.conf:28)
                 alias siteb.com

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that you have: 

ServerName "sitea.com"

So is the site sitea.com.au or is it sitea.com? And more importantly, how are you attempting to access the site(s) in a browser? Are you using the FQDN's that are properly defined in your conf file?

As mentioned above, you should change your VirtualHost lines to be  as it should be IP:Port, it is the ServerName that should denote the FQDN that is coming in.